# ASP .net Entity Framework Navigation Property Error

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, navigation-properties

I have the following schema (database first) :

[image]

I try to add related table in the Include property of EntityDataSource like this (with a dot) :

```
<asp:EntityDataSource ID="ServersEDS" runat="server"
        ConnectionString="name=InventoryEntities"
        DefaultContainerName="InventoryEntities"
        EnableFlattening="False" EntitySetName="Servers"
        Include="Domains, Tag_entites, Tag_Services, Tag_Services.Contact_Service">
    </asp:EntityDataSource>
```

But I have the folowing error (in french) :

*Un chemin d'accès Include spécifié n'est pas valide. L'EntityType 'InventoryModel.Contact_Service' ne déclare pas de propriété de navigation avec le nom 'Servers'.*

What's wrong?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Please translate the exception message. This is an English site.

Answer (score 0):

The provided entity diagram above clearly indicates that `Contact_Service` entity doesn't have navigation property named `Servers`, as the exception message said:

> The EntityType 'InventoryModel.Contact_Service' does not declare a
>   navigation property with the name 'Servers'.

Since you have set `EntitySetName="Servers"` in `EntityDataSource` as output entity, all entity names used in `Include` attribute must have navigation property with `Servers` entity, as in example below.

```
<asp:EntityDataSource ID="ServersEDS" runat="server"
    ConnectionString="name=InventoryEntities"
    DefaultContainerName="InventoryEntities"
    EnableFlattening="False" EntitySetName="Servers"
    Include="Domains, Tag_entites, Tag_Services, Datastores, Servers_IPs">
</asp:EntityDataSource>
```

If you want to include `Contact_Service` in EF data source definition above, put a navigation property to `Servers` entity in `Contact_Service` with foreign key relationship between both tables.

Comment: I thought it was possible as read it in a book Programming Entity Framework O'Reilly.

According to the following diagram (see url : https://i.stack.imgur.com/pmBBF.png) they can navigate from Contact to Destination by Customer.Reservation.Trip.Destination

Destination does not have a Contact property.

Why in my case I can't?